# Plotting each dataframe row separately (on separate plots) using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot each row of my 265 row dataframe using a for-loop. However, all the code does is it plots all the 265 rows in one single graph, rather than 265 separate graphs, which I am aiming for. Below is my code:

```
for q in range(265):
    print('This is for row',q)
    row = dataframe.iloc[q].plot()
    row.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Each call to plot() simply adds another artist to the currently opened plot. If you want to save your plots separately, your loop should open a new plot, plot() the graph in it, save it, then close it for each row in the dataframe.

Speaking of which - DataFrames have an iterrows method which will give you direct access to each row so that you don't have to locate by index on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=range(4))
for q in range(dataframe.shape[0]):
    print('This is for row',q)
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.plot(dataframe.iloc[q,:])
```